# How can I retrieve only the file name excluding the path when listing files in a Directory only?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm attempting to list all files inside of the directory excluding the path.(Ex: `sdcard/Appfolder/file1.txt -> file1`). I'm using this result to populate a spinner.

I have used "walktopdown" and "listFiles" to display all of the files in a specified directory. I was attempting to use a replace method to replace "sdcard/Appfolder/" and ".txt" with "" but realized I'm unable to do this with an array.

```
val dirlist = File("sdcard/Appfolder").walkTopDown().forEach { println(it) }
```

I also tried:

```
val f = File("sdcard/Appfolder")
val files = f.listFiles()
        println(files)
```

I'm using this to populate my spinner:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, files)
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

I'm attempting to just retrieve the file name excluding the path and extension. (Ex: File1, File2, File3)

Answer (score 1):

There's a property of Files called `nameWithoutExtension` that gives what you want.

```
val fileNames: List<String> = context.filesDir.walkTopDown().toList().map { it.nameWithoutExtension }
spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fileNames)
```

Comment: How am I able to populate my spinner using this method?

Answer (score 0):

```
//get list of files
val fileNames = context.filesDir.walkTopDown().toList().map { it.nameWithoutExtension }
//create the array adapter
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, fileNames)
// Set layout to use when the list of choices appear
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
// Set Adapter to Spinner
spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. `fileNames` is a String, not a `List<String>` so the array adapter line wouldn't compile. Buf if it did, you're creating a new array adapter for every file in the list, and by the end you only use the last one. Also, you're using `map` to return a Unit, so your're creating a list of Units for no reason.